# How to dump saved model without optimizer variables in tensorflow tf 1.11.0?

Tags: tensorflow

I trained tf model in python, dump saved model in python, load and inference in cpp.
I found that the saved model size in disk is triple than it should be, so as the memory usage when load and inference. That’s because saved model include optimizer related variables. So how to exclude those optimizer related variables when dump saved model in tf?

example notebook code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print 'tf.__version__', tf.__version__
! rm -rf tmp
! mkdir -p tmp/test_ckpt/
holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 3], name='fea1')
emb_table = tf.get_variable(
    shape=[int(1e7), 20],
    initializer=tf.initializers.random_uniform(minval=-0.04, maxval=0.04),
    dtype=tf.float32,
    name='emb_table',
    trainable=True)
emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_table, holder)
loss = pred = tf.reduce_sum(emb, name='pred')
optimzer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
    gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, visible_device_list='0'),
    allow_soft_placement=True))
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(optimzer, feed_dict={holder: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]})

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
saver.save(sess, 'tmp/test_ckpt/ckpt')
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, 'tmp/test_saved', 
    inputs={'fea1': holder,}, outputs={'pred': pred})
expect_size_in_mb = 1e7 * 20 * 4 / 1024 / 1024
print('expect_size_in_mb', expect_size_in_mb)
print('dump model size:')
! du -sh tmp/*
```

get output:
tf.version 1.11.0
(‘expect_size_in_mb’, 762.939453125)
dump model size:
763M tmp/test_ckpt
2.3G tmp/test_saved

I want a 763 MB saved model but it is 2.3 GB now.

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow 1.11.0, there has no save_traces=False or include_optimizer=False arguments, so I have to exclude optimizer variables by myself.
The method is simple:
First, build your graph, add optimizer, train by samples, and finally you dump a checkpoint, whether save optimizer variables or not does not matter here. Then stop this process.
Second, start a new process, rebuild tensorflow graph (your network), but DO NOT add optimizer into your graph. Then restore the former checkpoint and export as saved model. Since you do not add optimizer variables now, the restore function will ignore these optimizer variables in checkpoint.

example code of new process:

```
! rm -rf tmp/test_saved
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
    gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, visible_device_list='0'),
    allow_soft_placement=True))

holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 3], name='fea1')
emb_table = tf.get_variable(
    shape=[int(1e7), 20],
    initializer=tf.initializers.random_uniform(minval=-0.04, maxval=0.04),
    dtype=tf.float32,
    name='emb_table_shape',
    trainable=True)
emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_table, holder)
loss = pred = tf.reduce_sum(emb, name='pred')
# optimzer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, 'tmp/test_ckpt_all/ckpt')
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, 'tmp/test_saved',
    inputs={'fea1': holder,}, outputs={'pred': pred})
! du -sh tmp/*
```